# Filebeat POD getting killed due to OOM issue

Tags: kubernetes, filebeat, elk

We are running workloads in Kubernetes cluster, and to ship application logs out of the cluster we are using Filebeat as daemon set, which runs on dedicated namespace.

Filebeat sends the data to a Logstash cluster running behind a Load balancer.

We are seeing that some of the Filebeat pods are getting restarted due to OOM, we are trying to investigate the issue, but since running in Pod, we are reaching a deadlock.

Filebeat config:

```
filebeat.inputs:
- type: container
  paths:
    - /var/lib/docker/containers/*/*.log
  processors:
    - add_kubernetes_metadata:
        in_cluster: true
        host: ${NODE_NAME}
    - drop_event.when.not.or:
        - equals.kubernetes.labels.console-log: "enabled"
  exclude_lines: ["34mdebug"]
- type: log
  paths:
    - /var/log/node-log/messages
  include_lines:
    - 'kubelet:'
  exclude_lines:
    - 'CNI Plugin version'
  tags:
    - "kubelet-logs"
- type: log
  paths:
    - /mnt/logs/*.log
  tags:
    - "additional-logs"
processors:
  - drop_fields:
      fields: ["agent.ephemeral_id", "agent.hostname", "agent.id", "agent.name", "agent.type", "agent.version", "container.id", "container.image.name", "container.runtime", "kubernetes.container.image", "kubernetes.container.name", "kubernetes.namespace_labels.env", "kubernetes.namespace_labels.team", "kubernetes.namespace_uid", "kubernetes.node.hostname", "kubernetes.node.labels.beta_kubernetes_io/arch", "kubernetes.node.labels.beta_kubernetes_io/instance-type", "kubernetes.node.labels.beta_kubernetes_io/os", "kubernetes.node.labels.failure-domain_beta_kubernetes_io/region", "kubernetes.node.labels.failure-domain_beta_kubernetes_io/zone", "kubernetes.node.labels.kubernetes_io/arch", "kubernetes.node.labels.kubernetes_io/hostname", "kubernetes.node.labels.kubernetes_io/os", "kubernetes.node.labels.spotinst_io/node-lifecycle", "kubernetes.node.labels.vng-group", "kubernetes.node.name", "kubernetes.node.uid", "ecs.version", "input.type", "kubernetes.labels.app_kubernetes_io/managed-by", "kubernetes.labels.console-log", "kubernetes.pod.uid", "kubernetes.labels.app_kubernetes_io/name", "kubernetes.node.labels.node_kubernetes_io/instance-type", "kubernetes.node.labels.topology_kubernetes_io/region", "kubernetes.node.labels.topology_kubernetes_io/zone"]

cloud.id: ${ELASTIC_CLOUD_ID}
cloud.auth: ${ELASTIC_CLOUD_AUTH}      

fields:
  ekscluster: "eks-prod"

output.logstash:
  hosts: ["elk-logstash-internal.amazonaws.com:5043"]
  timeout: 60
```

On checking the pod logs, we are seeing this error:

```
Mar  3 08:35:57 ip-172-20-95-255 kernel: memory: usage 204760kB, limit 204800kB, failcnt 57072
Mar  3 08:35:57 ip-172-20-95-255 kernel: memory+swap: usage 204760kB, limit 9007199254740988kB, failcnt 0
Mar  3 08:35:57 ip-172-20-95-255 kernel: kmem: usage 2252kB, limit 9007199254740988kB, failcnt 0
Mar  3 08:35:57 ip-172-20-95-255 kernel: Memory cgroup stats for /kubepods/burstable/pod20b62bc0-c582-41ef-876a-58df4f4e073f: cache:0KB rss:0KB rss_huge:0KB shmem:0KB mapped_file:0KB dirty:0KB writeback:0KB swap:0KB inactive_anon:0KB acti
ve_anon:0KB inactive_file:0KB active_file:0KB unevictable:0KB
Mar  3 08:35:57 ip-172-20-95-255 kernel: Memory cgroup stats for /kubepods/burstable/pod20b62bc0-c582-41ef-876a-58df4f4e073f/0575ed6294aea6f4300b85da751d0239aa4d895efba7be3bdc7e4b9cdf0ba53f: cache:0KB rss:0KB rss_huge:0KB shmem:0KB mapped
_file:0KB dirty:0KB writeback:0KB swap:0KB inactive_anon:0KB active_anon:44KB inactive_file:0KB active_file:0KB unevictable:0KB
Mar  3 08:35:57 ip-172-20-95-255 kernel: Memory cgroup stats for /kubepods/burstable/pod20b62bc0-c582-41ef-876a-58df4f4e073f/cabb8b1f5425af10732fb04bee3437ad3c5d5c29cd7c2ebe2b5f9ddd3f18fc7c: cache:92KB rss:0KB rss_huge:0KB shmem:0KB mappe
d_file:0KB dirty:0KB writeback:0KB swap:0KB inactive_anon:0KB active_anon:0KB inactive_file:0KB active_file:0KB unevictable:0KB
Mar  3 08:35:57 ip-172-20-95-255 kernel: Memory cgroup stats for /kubepods/burstable/pod20b62bc0-c582-41ef-876a-58df4f4e073f/083febaeed20e6c5f494d84c1c53a7fb5978e618e7f42bec0fdbf1d4b3559918: cache:116KB rss:202276KB rss_huge:20480KB shmem
:0KB mapped_file:0KB dirty:0KB writeback:0KB swap:0KB inactive_anon:0KB active_anon:202408KB inactive_file:56KB active_file:0KB unevictable:0KB
Mar  3 08:35:58 ip-172-20-95-255 kernel: [ pid ]   uid  tgid total_vm      rss nr_ptes nr_pmds swapents oom_score_adj name
Mar  3 08:35:58 ip-172-20-95-255 kernel: [ 4283]     0  4283      242        1       3       2        0          -998 pause
Mar  3 08:35:58 ip-172-20-95-255 kernel: [ 1278]     0  1278     1092      160       8       3        0           975 tini
Mar  3 08:35:58 ip-172-20-95-255 kernel: [ 1303]     0  1303   275030    60940     168       4        0           975 filebeat
Mar  3 08:35:58 ip-172-20-95-255 kernel: Memory cgroup out of memory: Kill process 1303 (filebeat) score 2164 or sacrifice child
Mar  3 08:35:58 ip-172-20-95-255 kernel: Killed process 1303 (filebeat) total-vm:1100120kB, anon-rss:191432kB, file-rss:52328kB, shmem-rss:0kB
Mar  3 08:35:59 ip-172-20-95-255 kubelet: I0303 08:35:59.151720    2946 setters.go:77] Using node IP: "172.20.95.255"
Mar  3 08:35:59 ip-172-20-95-255 dockerd: time="2022-03-03T08:35:59.249926267Z" level=info msg="ignoring event" container=083febaeed20e6c5f494d84c1c53a7fb5978e618e7f42bec0fdbf1d4b3559918 module=libcontainerd namespace=moby topic=/tasks/de
lete type="*events.TaskDelete"
Mar  3 08:35:59 ip-172-20-95-255 containerd: time="2022-03-03T08:35:59.251109262Z" level=info msg="shim disconnected" id=083febaeed20e6c5f494d84c1c53a7fb5978e618e7f42bec0fdbf1d4b3559918
Mar  3 08:35:59 ip-172-20-95-255 containerd: time="2022-03-03T08:35:59.251188224Z" level=error msg="copy shim log" error="read /proc/self/fd/66: file already closed"
Mar  3 08:35:59 ip-172-20-95-255 kubelet: I0303 08:35:59.385350    2946 kubelet.go:1982] SyncLoop (PLEG): "filebeat-f4h8x_filebeat(20b62bc0-c582-41ef-876a-58df4f4e073f)", event: &pleg.PodLifecycleEvent{ID:"20b62bc0-c582-41ef-876a-58df4f4e
073f", Type:"ContainerDied", Data:"083febaeed20e6c5f494d84c1c53a7fb5978e618e7f42bec0fdbf1d4b3559918"}
Mar  3 08:35:59 ip-172-20-95-255 kubelet: I0303 08:35:59.386181    2946 topology_manager.go:221] [topologymanager] RemoveContainer - Container ID: 083febaeed20e6c5f494d84c1c53a7fb5978e618e7f42bec0fdbf1d4b3559918
Mar  3 08:35:59 ip-172-20-95-255 kubelet: I0303 08:35:59.387106    2946 topology_manager.go:221] [topologymanager] RemoveContainer - Container ID: a81a6bbc9d15d2ea0f51c7aad5eb1fa092c97b9826c86e0701ca93914ee5ce97
Mar  3 08:35:59 ip-172-20-95-255 containerd: time="2022-03-03T08:35:59.497230474Z" level=info msg="starting signal loop" namespace=moby path=/run/containerd/io.containerd.runtime.v2.task/moby/e956e035777aa655cb88d98efe5bb0a27208fd6ab67851
536a3cc3407d484bb3 pid=12405
Mar  3 08:36:00 ip-172-20-95-255 kubelet: I0303 08:36:00.413098    2946 kubelet.go:1982] SyncLoop (PLEG): "filebeat-f4h8x_filebeat(20b62bc0-c582-41ef-876a-58df4f4e073f)", event: &pleg.PodLifecycleEvent{ID:"20b62bc0-c582-41ef-876a-58df4f4e
073f", Type:"ContainerStarted", Data:"e956e035777aa655cb88d98efe5bb0a27208fd6ab67851536a3cc3407d484bb3"}
```

Memory and CPU Limit is

```
  limits:
            cpu: 250m
            memory: 200Mi
          requests:
            cpu: 40m
            memory: 100Mi
```

**Filebeat Version**  *7.11.2*

What can be the root cause and is there any way to investigate the issue.

Comment: [Here](https://github.com/elastic/beats/issues/26563) is a similar issue. As you can read solution is to increase the resource limits. Did you try it?